# How to get the node value of the name space 'xsi:type' from xml data?

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc-4, nodes

I have some  xml data  taken into a XDocument say 'xDoc' which is of the following format

```
<uketd_dc:uketddc xsi:schemaLocation ="http://naca.central.cranfield.ac.uk/ethos-oai/2.0/ http://naca.central.cranfield.ac.uk/ethos-oai/2.0/uketd_dc.xsd">
<dc:identifier>
http://www.google.com
</dc:identifier>

<dc:language>
en
</dc:language>

<dc:name>
Some name
</dc:name>

<dc:identifier xsi:type="dcterms:URI">
http://zzzz.com/zz.pdf?sequence=1
</dc:identifier>

</uketd_dc:uketddc>
```

I can get the value of 'dc:language' and 'dc:name' nodes using the below query

```
 var values= from e in xDoc.Descendants(uketd_dc + "uketddc")
                           select new Item(
                                e.Element(dc + "language").Value,
                                e.Element(dc + "name").Value
                                );
```

The problem is how to get the value of the last node?

```
<dc:identifier xsi:type="dcterms:URI">
http://zzzz.com/zz.pdf?sequence=1
</dc:identifier>
```

Comment: Well what happens if you just use `e.Element(dc + "identifier")`? `xsi:type` doesn't change the namespace of the element...

Comment: sorry forgot to mention I also have one nod named simply "identifier" so e.Element(dc + "identifier") returns its value.

Comment: So you mean you want to filter on xsi:type *as well* as element name?

Comment: yes exactly.How can I do it?

Comment: Well, firstly you should edit the question to make that clear, and secondly look at the answer Charles has given you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presuming you just want the value for the first `identifier` that has that type attribute:

```
 var uri = (string)e.Elements(dc + "identifier")
     .Where(e => (string)e.Attribute(xsi + "type") == "dcterms:URI")
     .FirstOrDefault()
```

Where `xsi` is the namespace for the prefix `xsi`, which *should* be as below:

```
XNamespace xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";
```